# Is it good practice to use node's child_process for executing an external script?

Tags: node.js, c, electron, frontend, exe

I have a text parsing program that is written in C. Now I want a cross platform frontend for it and want to use electronjs for it.
Is it good practice to run the C program from electron?

I am racking my brain about how to develop cross platform. I want to develop on Linux but have backend and frontend working in Windows or Mac with a single exe of app file.

Thanks in advance.

Edit: I mean I don't know what the child_process module was originally made for. Do you know that?

Comment: Is the text parsing code necessarily a program? Or is it a chunk of logic written in C that happens to be wrapped into an executable? If it's the later, you may want to look into compiling it to webasm.

Comment: It is a chunk of logic written in C. Can I use webasm together with electron? And can I put the webasm in another thread so the gui is smooth?

Comment: I don't see why you couldn't. There's nothing special about webasm that would forbid it. `worker_threads` doesn't play well with electron though IIRC, so it might be easier to do on the frontend side in a Web Worker.